# Why python class definition can refer to a concrete class instance name?

Tags: python, class, namespaces, instance, scoping

For example:

```
class abc:
     def show(self):
         print(self)
         print(a)

a = abc()
a.show()
```

Here `a` is an instance of the class, which can be directly referred to in the method by its name, in addition to by the first argument `self`.
Why is this allowed?

Comment: Why should it not be allowed?

Comment: class methods are not executed when the class is defined. When show is run `a` exists.

Comment: `a` is a global variable.  Why  do you think it should not be visible to a function?

Comment: What do you mean why is it allowed? Because it is allowed to refer to variables in the global scope... Why wouldn't this be allowed?

Comment: It turns out that my understanding of lexical scoping is wrong. `a` does not need to be created before the definition of the method. This applies also to ordinary function, not specific to class method.